# Exception in flutter mobile_number package

Tags: flutter

I use mobile_number plugin, when try to implement example code I have a error:

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method hasPhonePermission on channel mobile_number)
E/flutter (11696): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
E/flutter (11696): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11696): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
E/flutter (11696): #2      MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission (package:mobile_number/mobile_number.dart:32:24)
```

The line which generate error is:

```
  if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
```

I use Flutter 1.22.6 • channel stable
mobile_number: ^1.0.3

What is the reason and how to avoid such a mistake?

p/s
I installed permissions in Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that you added the plugin and didn't rebuild your app again. Given that you followed the documentation on the pluginpage and added the mainactivity java requirements correct as instructed.

1- Close your emulator\debugging session.

2- Run `flutter clean`.

3- Give it a new try and it should work, update on the results of these steps please.

Comment: I diid it but error still exist: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method hasPhonePermission on channel mobile_number)
E/flutter (12745): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)\n Something with plugin access...